# Как реализовать нейронную сеть для судоку

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как и какую (какого типа) сделать нейронную сеть для решения судоку?

Какие есть процедуры и методы в программе :

- NeuroGen - создаёт перцептрон (кстати, пойдёт для такой задачи обычный перцептрон?)
- NeuroGen.fill - забивает весы случайными значениями
- Game.MapGen - создаёт поле, а точнее массив из массива чисел, вида :

> ```
> [{4,8, ,6,5, , ,2,7};
>  {7, ,5,4,6, ,9,3,8};
>  ..
>                     ]
> ```

- Game.InsertIN(x,y,number) - вставляет число в клетку по координатам X и Y, возвращает false если была попытка вставить число в сгенерированную клетку.

Пару слов про Нейронную Сеть :

- Обучаться по идее должна с помощью генетического алгоритма
- Допустимые значения весов от 0 до 1

Ну вот сама программа (только алгоритм):

1. Я делаю структуру, а точнее обычный перцептрон
2. На весах генерирую различные значения от 0..1
3. Затем запускаю игру, ну а точнее в этой же программе генерирую поле с помощью процедуры `mapgen` (сразу же с пустыми клетками)

А дальше я не могу даже представить как заставить ходить мою НС, чтобы она обучалась и ходила сама основываясь на своём опыте.

В моей НС есть несколько входных слоёв, ну и вот какие мне подавать данные на вход и в каком формате, по сути я же должен подать окружающую среду (карту) и в конце цикла на выходном слое получить действие (позицию клетки и цифру какую надо ставить)?

И ещё, как подавать, пошагово? Тоесть клетека вставилась, НС отработала первый цикл, потом НС вставила в какую нибудь клетку цифру и до тех пор пока не останется пустых клеток, так вот и после того как она проиграет несколько игр, она же должна по идее скрестить те игры, у которых было меньше всего ошибок, правильно? Ну тогда как хранить данные, чтобы их можно было скрещивать?

И ещё, вот например мой алгоритм научиться играть на этой карте, а на других он сможет выигрывать?

Comment: Какая цель - научиться делать нейронные сети, или решать судоку? Судоку вообще достаточно легко решается перебором.

Comment: Нейронные сети хороши там, где другие алгоритмы не справляются, или требуют слишком много усилий разработчиков. В случае с судоку нет смысла применять нейронные сети.

Comment: Напомнило ту историю, где человек решал с помощью многослойного перцептрона задачу "FizzBuzz"

Comment: @Александр ну и чё, он решил? )

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, лучше эту историю прочитать целиком: https://habrahabr.ru/post/301536/  :)